# iOS double tap issues on image mobile screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ios, shopify

We're developing an ecommerce website, which has some problems on ios mobiles.
**The problem is the following:**

When we click on the thumbnails -  the product's variant title should change based on the thumbnail image. It's working perfectly on Windows, Android but for some reason on ios it requires the double tap and it's not really good like this.

We have no idea why is this happening. Any suggestions? Appreciate!

**Our full code is the following which also initiates the changes for the thumbnails:**

```
    const allVariants = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('em_product_variants').innerText);
    const allColorTypes = document.querySelectorAll(`[name="main color"]`);
    let allColorActive = false;
    
    for(let elem of allColorTypes) {
        elem.addEventListener("change", function(e){
            const target = e.currentTarget;
            if(target.id != "showAll") {
                allColorActive = false;
                return;
            }
            document.querySelector(`[data-color-2] .swatches__option-value`).innerText = "All Colors";
            allColorActive = true;
        })
    }
    
    const allColorRadio = document.querySelectorAll(`[name="color"], [name="choose color"]`);
    for(let elem of allColorRadio) {
        elem.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
            const target = e.currentTarget
            
            //show the image in slider
            //get the selected variant value
            const imageValue = target.value;
    
            let selectedVariant = "";
            for(let variant of allVariants) {
                const option1 = variant.option1;
    
                if(imageValue == option1) {
                    selectedVariant = variant;
                    break;
                }
            }
    
            if(allColorActive ==  false) {
                showTheName(selectedVariant)
                return;
            }
    
            //get image id 
            const imageID = selectedVariant.featured_media.id;

            //set variant as selected
            console.log("option1 ", selectedVariant.option1);
            console.log("option2 ", selectedVariant.option2)
            document.querySelector(`.product__section--buttons [method="post"] .formVariantId[name="id"]`).value = selectedVariant.id;
            document.querySelector(`.product__section--buttons [method="post"] .formVariantId[name="id"]`).setAttribute("value", selectedVariant.id)
          
            //click on thumb
            console.log("imageValue",imageValue)
            console.log("imageID",imageID)
            document.querySelector(`.js-thumb-item-img[data-image-id="${imageID}"]`).click()
            console.log(selectedVariant)
            showTheName(selectedVariant)
        })
    }
    
    function showTheName(variant) {
      document.querySelector(`#wisn-variant-title span`).innerText = "";
        if(variant.option2) {
          document.querySelector(`#wisn-variant-title span`).innerText += variant.option2 + " / "
        }
        if(variant.option1) {
           document.querySelector(`#wisn-variant-title span`).innerText +=" "+ variant.option1
        }
    }

    const allThumbs = document.querySelectorAll(`#thumbnails div[data-image-id]`);

//add eventListeners for thumbs
for(let elem of allThumbs) {
    elem.addEventListener("click",selectVariantByThumb, false);
}

function selectVariantByThumb(e) {
    const target = e.currentTarget;
    const targetImageId = target.dataset.imageId;

    //going through all the variants
    for (let variant of allVariants) {
        const imageId = variant.featured_media.id;

        if(imageId == targetImageId) {
            const imageUrl = variant.featured_media.preview_image.src.replace("https:","")
            document.querySelector(`[data-image-src*="${imageUrl}"]`)?.click();
            

          document.querySelector(`.product__section--buttons [method="post"] .formVariantId[name="id"]`).value = variant.id;
          document.querySelector(`.product__section--buttons [method="post"] .formVariantId[name="id"]`).setAttribute("value", variant.id)
        }
    }
}
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      document.querySelector(`[name="color"]:checked`)?.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))
      document.querySelector(`[name="choose color"]:checked`)?.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))

      document.querySelector('#showAll')?.click()
    })
```

**This code builds up the thumbnails:**

```
<div class="variant-name-changer" id="wisn-variant-title"><span></span></div>
    <div id="thumbnails" class="thumb-slider thumbnail-slider custom {{ style }} {{ width }} auto mobile-hide"
    data-thumbnail-position="{{ thumbnail_position }}">
      <div class="thumb-slider-wrapper {{ js_class }} js-thumb-wrapper" id="thumb-slider-wrapper">
        <div class="carousel-nav thumb-slider-slides slides product-single__thumbnails-{{ section.id }} js-thumb-carousel-nav{% if product.media.size <4 %} no_carousel{% endif %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I used FastClick to solve this problem. FastClick is a lightweight javascript routine, and while not designed really to solve this double-click problem, it did for me.

I only struggled with this double-tap issue when images were contained in anchor tags, but others have used FastClick to solve a variety of double-tap issues on ios devices.

See, [css-tricks for an explanation of the double-tap issue](https://css-tricks.com/annoying-mobile-double-tap-link-issue/)
and [github for an explanation of FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)